# Bash shell: how to add a name

Tags: bash, shell, rename

I am trying to rename some zip files in bash with an _orig but I seem to be missing something.  Any suggestions??

My goal:

- move files to an orig directory
- rename original files with a "_orig" in the name

The code Ive tried to write:

```
mv -v  $PICKUP/*.zip $ORIGINALS
for origfile in $(ls $ORIGINALS/*.zip);do
    echo "Adding _orig to zip file"
    echo
    added=$(basename $origfile '_orig').zip
    mv -v $ORIGINALS/$origfile.zip $ORIGINALS/$added.zip
done
```

Sorry still kinda new at this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using (p)rename :

```
cd <ZIP DIR>
mkdir -p orig
rename 's@(.*?)\.zip@orig/$1_orig.zip@' *.zip
```

`rename` is http://search.cpan.org/~pederst/rename/ (default on many distros)

Thanks to never use

```
for i in $(ls $ORIGINALS/*.zip);do
```

but use *globs* instead :

```
for i in $ORIGINALS/*.zip;do
```

See http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#ls.

Answer (score 1):

I know you've got a solution already, but just for posterity, this simplified version of your own shell script should also work for the case you seem to be describing:

```sh
mkdir -p "$ORIGINALS"
for file in "$PICKUP"/*.zip; do
    mv -v "$file" "$ORIGINALS/${file%.zip}_orig.zip"
done
```

This makes use of "Parameter Expansion" in bash (you can look that up in bash's man page).  The initial `mkdir -p` simply insures that the target directory exists.  The quotes around `$PICKUP` and `$ORIGINALS` are intended to make it safe to include special characters like spaces and newlines in the directory names.

While `prename` is a powerful solution to many problems, it's certainly not the only hammer in the toolbox.